# Print first and last non-empty (or non-whitespaces only) line in a file

Tags: text-processing

I want to print the first and the last non-empty or non-whitespace-only line in a file, idally using `sed` or `awk`.

- Input File:

  ```
  123 345
  456 087
  er 56
  32 78
  ```

  Note that there is a blank line after `32 78`.
- Desired output:

  ```
  123 345
  32 78
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that I'm answering two questions here as the text in the question was modified:

1. How may we output the first and the penultimate lines from a file (the initial question contained the wording "second last line")?
2. How may we output the first line, and the last non-empty, non-blank line?

---

Using the `ed` editor, which is slightly more flexible with its addressing of lines than `sed`, mostly due to reading all of the data into memory rather than a line at a time:

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' 1p '$-1p' Q | ed -s file
123 345
32 78
```

This prints the first and penultimate line from the input file before quitting.  The penultimate line is addressed using `$-1`, which could be shortened to just `$-`.

If we don't know that there's exactly one blank line at the end, we may instead search backwards from line 1 for a line that contains something and print that:

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' 1p '?[[:graph:]]?p' Q | ed -s file
123 345
32 78
```

---

Using `sed`:

```bash
$ sed -n -e 1p -e '${ g; p; }' -e h file
123 345
32 78
```

This first turns off the default outputting of each line with `-n`.  It then prints the first line.  All lines are saved to the hold space using `h`, and on the last line, we fetch the hold space with `g` and print it.  Due to the ordering of the last two expressions, this will print the penultimate line.

With a small modification, we can change this to output the last non-blank line, no matter if it's the penultimate one or not:

```bash
$ sed -n -e 1p -e '/[[:graph:]]/h' -e '${ g; p; }' file
123 345
32 78
```

---

With a combination of `grep` and `sed`, we may first filter out all empty or empty-looking lines, and then just output the first and last lines:

```bash
$ grep '[[:graph:]]' file | sed -n -e 1p -e '$p'
123 345
32 78
```

Note that this will also output the first non-empty line, even if this is not the first line in the original data.

Answer (score 2):

The following  `awk` program will do this:

```
awk 'NF{last=$0; if (!c++) print;} END {if (c>1) print last}' file.txt
```

- `awk` by default splits input lines into fields at "whitespace", i.e. contiguous runs of space and tabs. The number of fields is stored in `NF`. If a line is completely empty, or only consists of whitespace, `NF` will be zero.
- If the program encounters a truly and visually non-empty line, i.e. `NF` is non-zero and evaluates to `true`, it stores the line content in a buffer `last`. If this is the first such line (the counter variable `c` will be unset and evaluate to `false`), it prints the current line. In any case, it increases `c` so that this condition can only occur once, for the first non-empty line.
- At the end, if prints `last`, the content of the last non-empty line, *but only if `c>1`*, so that if only a single line is non-empty, that line will just be printed once. If all lines were empty, `c` will evaluate to 0, and nothing will be printed even in the `END` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/^$/d; p; :a; n; /^$/!h; $!ba; g; /^$/!p' file.txt
```

**Test files content:**

```
==> file_1.txt <==
123 345
456 087

er 56

32 78

==> file_2.txt <==    

123 345
456 087

er 56

32 78    

==> file_3.txt <==
123 345
456 087

er 56

32 78
==> file_4.txt <==


123 345
456 087

er 56

32 78  


==> file_5.txt <==
123 345
```

**Testing**

```
for f in file_{1..5}.txt; do
    echo "==> $f <=="
    sed -n '/^$/d; p; :a; n; /^$/!h; $!ba; g; /^$/!p' "$f"
done
```

**Output:**

```
==> file_1.txt <==
123 345
32 78
==> file_2.txt <==
123 345
32 78
==> file_3.txt <==
123 345
32 78
==> file_4.txt <==
123 345
32 78
==> file_5.txt <==
123 345
```

Comment: Note that in its current form(`/^$/`), your script will not deal correctly with "visually empy" lines, i.e. lines that contain only whitespace.

Comment: @AdminBee Yes, I didn't think about processing lines with whitespaces only as empty ones.